# What does "final" mean in PHP?

Tags: php, final

```
final static public function registerAutoload(){}
```

Comment: Couldn’t [the manual](http://php.net/language.oop5.final) answer this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use "final"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526312/when-should-i-use-final)

Answer (score 4):

It effectively means that sub-classes cannot override this method, or as the [PHP final keyword documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) states:

> "...prevents child classes from
>   overriding a method by prefixing the
>   definition with final. If the class
>   itself is being defined final then it
>   cannot be extended."

Comment: @BoltClock - Good save. Fixed now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Here's your +1 for being first :D

Comment: What's the difference between override and overload?

Comment: @lex - Overloading is where you have multiple methods with the same name, but different signatures. It isn't something that's supported by PHP, in the main due to the fact that it's inherently typeless and hence such things don't really make sense. (Incidentally, don't confuse this with PHP's property/method overloading which is a different thing - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Answer (score 0):

It means a child class **cannot override** the method `registerAutoload`.

Comment: What's the difference between override and overload?

Answer (score 0):

The same as in every other language: any class that extends another containing a `final` method cannot override that specific method.