# why we use 'final',could you give me an example in real world?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I use “final”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526312/when-should-i-use-final)

PHP has a keyword 'final', 
Could you give me an example in real world that use this keyword.

I just don't know when to use.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php): *PHP 5 introduces the final keyword, which prevents child classes from overriding a method by prefixing the definition with final. If the class itself is being defined final then it cannot be extended.* Do you need any more information than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a real world, let's say you are a senior developer and you wrote some base class, and told those junior guys your idea and let them code the rest classes, and you don't trust them and want to 100% make sure they will not try to override some certain method and make the system crash.

Answer (score 1):

Final is used when you are extending classes. If you have a method within the parent you do not want overwritten, then use final. This is a useful feature when multiple extends come into play.. ie.. Class A extends B extends C etc etc.

Class B have have a function that you never want overriding, so you use final..

Answer (score 0):

one among others:

```
class SysInformation {
  ...
  final public function getExactMemoryUsage() {
    // here a complicated calculation of the current memory usage
    // calculation is distorted if the method is overrided
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```